# jquery click on href link - have to click twice

Tags: jquery, popup, click

The function works, but the popup will open only after the button is clicked twice (and then, subsequent clicks get the action on the first click).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#printPosBtn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.printPopup').popupWindow({ 
            centerBrowser:1,
            height:500,
            width:720,
            scrollbars: 1,
            resizable: 1
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` does the same thing as `return false;` in your code.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with the code.  We would probably have to see the actual page in order to debug why that is happening.

Comment: yeah, you're seriously defeating your own cause using a double cancel like that.  Also, you're using some very old style work on jquery, you know your could easily rewrite that easier `$(function() { $("#printPosBtn").click(function(event){ e.preventDefault(); /* do finish work */ }); });`

Comment: @elclanrs - The "return false" and the "preventDefault" is a test I've made on debug...The original code was more like the click event that karim79 sent. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is because you are actually initialising the plugin within the `click` handler. From a quick skim through the `popupWindow` docs it appears that the plugin takes care of binding a `click` handler for you, which means that your first click binds the popup functionality (including an onclick handler) so it only works upon click a second time. I would try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".printPopup").popupWindow({
        centerBrowser: 1,
        height: 500,
        width: 720,
        scrollbars: 1,
        resizable: 1
    });

    // open popup by clicking on some other element
    $('#printPosBtn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".printPopup").click();         
    });

});​
```