# Magnific popup with Backbone only fires after second click

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, magnific-popup

The issue I'm having is pretty similar to this [jquery click on href link - have to click twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251916/jquery-click-on-href-link-have-to-click-twice) . The image popup works fine after the first click,

> *as it appears that the plugin takes care of binding a click handler
>   for you, which means that your first click binds the popup
>   functionality (including an onclick handler) so it only works upon
>   click a second time.*

I use Backbone 1.0.0 with require.js.

My code is as follows:

Backbone view

```
events:{
'click .test-popup-link':'popImg',
}

popImg: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        //closeBtnInside: false,
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        overflowY: 'auto',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
          verticalFit: true
        }
      });

    },
```

The HTML

```
   <div class='test-popup-link'><a class='image-popup-vertical-fit'        href="http://mydomain.com/files/8e0183d4179a11e2880f22000a1e8aaf_7%20(15).jpg"><img id='6576465avt7a6768'       src="http://mydomain.com/files/8e0183d4179a11e2880f22000a1e8aaf_7%20(15).jpg"></a></div>;
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in your view's  `initialize` function like this:

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".open-popup-link"),
    initialize: function () {
        $(this.el).magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline',
            midClick: true
        });
    }
});
var search_view = new SearchView();
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cardiff/UWXNd/

Comment: Thanks a lot,  it kind of works - now it opens at first attempt -  but the popup lost its styling, it opens the image as a new URL, not actually an overlay popup over the same view. Do you know what could be wrong? Thanks

Comment: I did not use your settings, you should be using the ones in your code. I suppose that can be the problem, like the `type: 'inline'` etc.